# What can't you do in Brawl with a sideways wii remote controller, and does using a nunchuk fix this?

Tags: controllers, super-smash-bros-brawl

I noticed in the accepted answer to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20842/how-can-i-become-a-pro-at-super-smash-bros-brawl) that there are some things you can't do with a sideways wii remote in Brawl. We are brawl newbies, so I wanted to ask what other things are either trickier or impossible to do in Brawl with just a sideways wii remote and does getting a Nunchuk to play with fix this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are quite a few difficulties you'll run into by using the Wiimote-alone controls.

**Showstoppers**

- You cannot use the up tilt attack properly. Up tilts are used by attacking while pressing up without smashing. But on the Wiimote, pressing up is always considered a smash (it makes you jump), so the only way to use an up tilt is to begin holding up during some other action (so that when the action's over you're holding up and a smash is not recognized).
- It is difficult if not impossible (or at least it is for me) to angle forward tilts. Quite a few f-tilts can be angled up or down, which alters their damage and hitbox location, but you have to have a very precise vertical position of the control stick which I don't think a D-pad can replicate. F-smashes can be angled because you can just hold up or down before the charge interval ends, but f-tilts have to be angled on startup.

**Issues**

- Special moves that use analog controls are harder to manipulate. Examples include Quick Attack, PK Thunder, and Fire Fox: your ability to aim them is heavily limited.
- The default shield button is `B`, which isn't exactly in a convenient location.
- The default grab button is either `-` (which is even more out-of-the way than the shield button) or `A+B` (which if you don't get it right might make you taunt instead).
- You cannot shift your shield. With a control stick you can reposition your shield by moving the stick around. But with a D-pad, pressing any direction results in enough of an input to cause you to jump, roll, or sidestep. Shield shifting is useful if your shield is a bit small and you can see an attack going for an exposed bit.

**Niggles**

- There is no "quick smash" option like the Gamecube/Classic controller's C-Stick or the Wiimote+Nunchuk's Shake Smash. Yes you can get a quick f-smash by pressing `1+2`, but the other two smashes don't have an equivalent (pressing `1+2` with up or down is basically the same result as just `2`.)
- You cannot walk slowly.

**Notes**

- You can shorthop with Wiimote-alone, and it's no tricker than with other controllers.

Using a Wiimote-Nunchuck will fix all these problems; having a control stick really is the way to go and all the button functions are in more accesible locations (except for maybe the side taunt). Smash Bros. was simply not designed for D-pad use.

Answer (score 2):

I have found it to be much more difficult to phase through floors that you pass through with the wiimote. You would have to double tap extremly fast so it sometimes takes a few tries.

Also note, performing short-hops for areal attacks (which helps reduce lag for many moves) is very difficult with the wiimote.