# How can I use the D-pad of my classic controller like the one on the Wii-Mote?

Tags: super-smash-bros-brawl

I just bought a Classic Controller Pro for my Wii (mainly to play old (S)NES games on the emulator). However, I just thought it would be a great idea to try it out with SSBB. When I play SSBB I use the Wii-Mote without Nunchuck in the horizontal position, which allows me to control movement with the D-pad.

In the configuration menu I found, I cannot figure out how to map the Classic Controller's D-pad to the same functionality (by default, you move with the left analog stick). I refuse to believe that it's impossible, but all I can choose for the left-right-arrows is: Attack, Special, Jump, Shield, Grab and Horizontal-Mock. Similarly for the down-arrow.

Is there some hack or trick to configure the D-pad. I mean, the Classic Controller is a superset of the Wii-Mote. Why would you exclude the most obvious choice for the D-pad?

Comment: The controllers are simply different things to the Wii so, to the best of my knowledge, some games just always ignore the Classic controller or don't map it the way you want. I don't believe there's any way to do this without hacking the wii or the actual controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brawl does not allow you to use the D-pad for movement if there is a control stick available (on any controller, Classic or otherwise). There are legitimate reasons for this; [using the D-pad instead of a control stick will gimp your controls slightly](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/46168/what-cant-you-do-in-brawl-with-a-sideways-wii-remote-controller-and-does-using). I believe this also has to do with how the control maps are coded - because up, down, and side are different functions in non-Wiimote alone setups, you can't "merge" the whole thing into "movement" and "jump". (They had to carve up a few mechanics to squeeze the game into the D-pad anyway, it gimped parts of the game engine itself.) It's the exception; the control stick is the rule (and indeed the crux of the series).

Of course there are probably hacks for this, but I don't know any offhand.

Comment: Well, even if it is "gimped" in theory, I found out that I can play a lot better with a discrete input like the D-pad than the analog stick (I often push slightly into the wrong direction). I guess I will have to continue using the Wiimote :/

Comment: Well, it's your choice, but in my opinion you're only hurting yourself by not learning to use the intended controls. The fundemental concept of Smash Bros. revolves around the control stick and quite honestly I have no idea why they ruined several mechanics just so people could play with the Wiimote alone.

Comment: Okay, convinced. I'll follow your advice and git it a shot :)