# Can I use the D-Pad to move around?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

I've been considering getting Super Smash Bros. for 3DS, but using the Slide Pad for movement has proven extremely inconvenient in the demo.

Unfortunately, the demo did not allow for configuration and I couldn't find any definite answers online, nor did the salespeople know whom I asked.

In case I can't use the D-Pad, I've decided to wait for the Wii U version with which I'll just play using a simple Wiimote.

Comment: I suggest you be forewarned that using the "Wiimote alone" controls in Brawl is [objectively worse](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/46168/what-cant-you-do-in-brawl-with-a-sideways-wii-remote-controller-and-does-using) than any other control option, and I expect that SSB4-U would be no different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly, there is no option in the controls menu to assign movement to the d-pad.

The only thing you can do with the slide pad, is switch off/on if up should jump

The d-pad is for taunting.

[image]

Comment: Looks like I'll just have to wait for the Wii U version then, thanks.